# Codefights: avoidObstacles, multiple return inside a function

Tags: python, return

I'm practicing coding at codefights.com. Here's a link to see what they're asking for: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/derZJ.jpg). I'm having struggle to understand what these return statements really do in the code below.

My code:

```
def avoidObstacles(inputArray):

    for i in range(1, max(inputArray)):
        divs = any([x for x in inputArray if not x%i])
        if not divs:
            return i

    return max(inputArray) + 1
```

I don't understand how `return max(inputArray) +1` gives the right answer.

For example: 
`inputArray = [5,3,6,7,9]` should return "4".

I'd really appreciate if someone could walk me through step by step.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I will try to visualize the code for you to show how this works:

```
>>> for i in range(1, max(inputArray)):
...     print("hop " + str(i),[x for x in inputArray if not x%i])
...
('hop 1', [5, 3, 6, 7, 9])
('hop 2', [6])
('hop 3', [3, 6, 9])
('hop 4', [])
('hop 5', [5])
('hop 6', [6])
('hop 7', [7])
('hop 8', [])
```

You can imagine that these are the hop lengths. You can see a hop length of "1" will hit every obstacle, but a hop length of "2" only hits obstacle number 6.

Notice on hop 4 there is nothing in the array. This is where the `any` keyword comes in, to basically make this True/False:

```
>>> for i in range(1, max(inputArray)):
...     print(any([x for x in inputArray if not x%i]))
...
True
True
True
False
True
True
True
False
```

You can see as the code executes, when `i == 4`, `divs == False`, so you will trigger this logic:

```
if not divs:   
        return i
```

However, in the case where every single hop hits an obstacle so you never have `divs == False`, the answer is simply hop the entire thing! In this problem "entire thing" is the length of `max(inputArray)+1`

Comment: Ok, but `return i` should return 4 and 8. I don't see how `return max(inputArray) + 1` should return 4. I don't understand what's happening between `return i` and `return max(inputArray) +1`

Comment: This function will only `return` once, so the first return reached is the only one that "matters". I updated the answer for a little more clarity.

Answer (score 2):

```py
def avoidObstacles(inputArray):
    for i in range(2, max(inputArray)):
        quantity = 0
        for x in inputArray:
            if x % i == 0:
                break
            quantity +=1
        if quantity == len(inputArray):
            return i
    return max(inputArray) + 1
```

Minimal step to avoid obstacles is 2 and maximal can be biggest number in *inputArray*, whats why loop is `for i in range(2, max(inputArray))`

For each element in *inputArray* I check if it divides by *step* (variable *x* in loop) and if no then increase *quantity* by 1. If *quantity* is equal to length of *inputArray* e.g. none element in *inputArray* doesn't divide by *step* then this is needed *step*. In case of this loop is empty we need return *max(inputArray) + 1* as smallest posible step to avoid all obstacles.

Comment: Please elaborate. How does this piece of code solve the problem. Explain.

Comment: @OrestisZekai I just add explanation to my answer